# SVG output is stretched

Tags: svg, geogebra

The SVG file in the following link is stretched horizontally in a bad way:

http://isometricland.net/svg/openworld_sandbox_nonlinear_venndiagram_bugreport.svg

I was wondering if there were a quick way to fix the file by editing the source?

Unfortunately, the developer of the software GeoGebra which I used to create the file is slow when it comes to fixing bugs and I am in a hurry. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

[edit]

Here's what it should look like, roughly.

[image: three circles in a square]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `viewBox` attribute in the root `<svg>` element to the following.

```
viewBox="0 0 1605 887"
```

You may also want to change the `width` and `height` attributes to something more suitable.  Use

```
width="100%" height="100%"
```

if you want it to fit inside a parent `<div>` or something.  Or specify an exact size if you want that.  Make sure you use a width and height with the same aspect ratio though (1615/897).

**Update**

**Option 1:** To make it display as a square, you need to change the `viewBox` as above, but also change the `preserveAspectRatio` setting.  Make the following changes to the root `<svg>` element.

```
viewBox="0 0 1605 887"
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

The diagram will still be very large because the width and height are set to "60cm".  If you want it smaller, just change these to something more suitable - eg. "600px".  Or, if you want, make them "100%" as above and put them in a square `<div>`.

**Option 2:** Or as an alternative to the above, you can add a `transform` to the first `<g>` element (that wraps the whole diagram).

```
<g stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-dashoffset="0.0000" stroke-dasharray="none"
   stroke-width="1.0000" stroke-miterlimit="10.000" stroke-linecap="square"
   transform="scale(0.474 0.858)">
```

This transform is equivalent to the implicit transform that the changed viewBox above is causing.

The comments, in Option 1, about changing the width and height, apply here also.

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome or IE 11. The image is still stretched horizontally.

Comment: What do you mean by "stretched"?  I thought you meant that it was very large and that, in particular, parts were off the edge of the page.  Is that not what you meant?  Perhaps you could explain exactly what you mean.

Comment: I posted a PNG image of what it's _supposed_ to look like. Sorry I didn't include that at first.